# SQL select distinct but "keep first"?

Tags: mysql, sql

According to another SO post ([SQL: How to keep rows order with DISTINCT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026234/sql-how-to-keep-rows-order-with-distinct)), distinct has pretty undefined behavior as far as sorting.

I have a query:

```
select col_1 from table order by col_2
```

This can return values like

```
3
5
3
2
```

I need to then select a distinct on these that preserves ordering, meaning I want

```
select distinct(col_1) from table order by col_2
```

to return

```
3
5
2
```

but not

```
5
3
2
```

Here is what I am actually trying to do. Col_1 is a user id, and col_2 is a log in timestamp event by that user. So the same user (col_1) can have many login times. I am trying to build a historical list of users in which they were seen in the system. I would like to be able to say "our first user ever was, our second user ever was", and so on.

That post seems to suggest to use a group by, but group by is not meant to return an ordering of rows, so I do not see how or why this would be applicable here, since it does not appear group by will preserve any ordering. In fact, another SO post gives an example where group by will destroy the ordering I am looking for: see "Peter" in [what is the difference between GROUP BY and ORDER BY in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277460/what-is-the-difference-between-group-by-and-order-by-in-sql). Is there anyway to guarantee the latter result? The strange thing is, if *I* were implementing the DISTINCT clause, I would surely do the order by first, then take the results and do a linear scan of the list and preserve the ordering naturally, so I am not sure why the behavior is so undefined.

EDIT:

Thank you all! I have accepted IMSoP answer because not only was there an interative example that I could play around with (thanks for turning me on to SQL Fiddle), but they also explained why several things worked the way they worked, instead of simply "do this". Specifically, it was unclear that GROUP BY does not destroy (rather, keeps them in some sort of internal list) values in the other columns outside of the group by, and these values can still be examined in an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I believe you will need to do that type of data processing upon retrieval of the data. That is functionality that I have never heard of being implemented.

Comment: Are there multiple col_2's for each col_1, or is it 1 to 1?

Comment: If you don't provide an `ORDER BY` clause there is never a guarantee on the order of the data. If you want it in a specific order you **must** use order by.

Comment: Yes, Distinct will pull each distinct entry in the DB and exclude the rows where the value for the designated Distinct column is the same. Very good for seeing all values that a column maintains without retrieving a query over 1000 rows

Comment: i guess my question is if N rows have the same value, which 1 of the N does it keep? I need it to keep the first with respect to an order by clause.

Comment: I would try mucio's suggestion, I think that should work.

Comment: Well I'm using mysql 5.6 but I was thinking that DISTINCT is probably defined somewhere in the SQL standard.

Comment: I will repeat Andrew's question: Are there multiple _col2's_ for _the same col1_? And if so, which _col2_ of those should be taken into account to order the corresponding _col1_?

Comment: There is no undefined behaviour. It's pretty much defined: **Queries without `ORDER BY` can return their result sets in any order.** If you want a specific order, use `ORDER BY`. If you don't have `ORDER BY`, you have a table as a result. And order does not matter for tables.

Comment: The undefined behavior is with respect to DISTINCT. If you run DISTINCT On a set of values, and there are 2 copies of item "X", it is unknown, atleast according to that other SO post, whether the first instance of "x" or the second instance of "x" is removed.

Comment: @ypercube But the example in the question *does* have an `ORDER BY`. I don't know why people keep commenting as though it didn't.

Comment: @Tommy Why would anyone care about that? Does it matter if `'Alex'` or `'Alex'` is returned? Can you spot a difference between the two?

Comment: @IMSoP Are you referring to the `select distinct col_1 from table order by col_2 ;`? That is not even valid SQL!

Comment: @ypercube. Yes. If I have a list 3,5,3, there is a difference between (5,3) and (3,5), which are two possible outputs of DISTINCT(3,5,3). The first can be said to be "temporally" sorted in which the elements appear.

Comment: Well, tables are not lists of rows. That's the confusion.

Comment: @ypercube Well, there are two sample queries in the question, and both use "order by". Whether or not they're valid, the clear intention is to use "order by", so I don't understand why you'd mention queries *without* "order by".

Comment: @IMSoP I mentioned that because the OP says in the last paragraph: *"The strange thing is, if I were implementing the DISTINCT clause, I would surely do the order by first, then take the results and do a linear scan of the list and preserve the ordering naturally, so I am not sure why **the behavior is so undefined**."* after he links to a question with queries that do not have `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Q: you have a vase with 10 red and 10 blue balls. select the _first_ red ball. A: first define _first_, please ...

Comment: This is not the question. The question is more like "user red logged in 10 times, user blue logged in 10 times, and user green logged in 10 times. Who was the first user ever? Who was the second user we ever saw? Who was the third?

Comment: @Tommy: I beg to differ. The question is about _selecting_ the first ball, not about selecting the ball that was _inserted_ first. (but I think we agree, essentially ...)

Comment: I am trying to select the ball that was inserted first. That "first" red ball has some special property over the others. So in your question, define "first" is defined as "inserted first", which is what the ORDER BY (col_2 = timestamp) in my original question was for.

Comment: @Tommy: there is no first, unless it was written down in the record (for example, by means of a timestamp or a sequence number). Without that, all red balls are red, and none of them can be picked as the _first_.

Comment: If you read my question, col_2 is a timestamp, and the order by clause is on that timestamp.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This all has to do with the "logical ordering" of SQL statements. Although a DBMS might actually retrieve the data according to all sorts of clever strategies, it has to behave according to some predictable logic. As such, the different parts of an SQL query can be considered to be processed "before" or "after" one another in terms of how that logic behaves.

As it happens, the `ORDER BY` clause is the very last step in that logical sequence, so it can't change the behaviour of "earlier" steps.

If you use a `GROUP BY`, the rows have been bundled up into their groups by the time the `SELECT` clause is run, let alone the `ORDER BY`, so you can only look at columns which have been grouped by, or "aggregate" values calculated across all the values in a group. (MySQL implements [a controversial extension to `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) where you can mention a column in the `SELECT` that can't logically be there, and it will pick one from an arbitrary row in that group).

If you use a `DISTINCT`, it is logically processed *after* the `SELECT`, but the `ORDER BY` still comes afterwards. So only once the `DISTINCT` has thrown away the duplicates will the remaining results be put into a particular order - but the rows that have been thrown away can't be used to determine that order.

---

As for how to get the result you need, the key is to find a value to sort by which is valid *after* the `GROUP BY`/`DISTINCT` has (logically) been run. Remember that if you use a `GROUP BY`, any aggregated values are still valid - an aggregate function can look at all the values in a group. This includes `MIN()` and `MAX()`, which are ideal for ordering by, because "the lowest number" (`MIN`) is the same thing as "the first number if I sort them in ascending order", and vice versa for `MAX`.

So to order a set of distinct `foo_number` values based on the lowest applicable `bar_number` for each, you could use this:

```
SELECT foo_number
FROM some_table
GROUP BY foo_number
ORDER BY MIN(bar_number) ASC
```

[Here's a live demo with some arbitrary data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d58f7/2).

---

***EDIT:*** In the comments, it was discussed why, if an ordering is applied before the grouping / de-duplication takes place, that order is not applied to the groups. If that were the case, you would still need a strategy for which row was kept in each group: the first, or the last.

As an analogy, picture the original set of rows as a set of playing cards picked from a deck, and then sorted by their face value, low to high. Now go through the sorted deck and deal them into a separate pile for each suit. Which card should "represent" each pile?

If you deal the cards face up, the cards showing at the end will be the ones with the *highest* face value (a "keep last" strategy); if you deal them face down and then flip each pile, you will reveal the *lowest* face value (a "keep first" strategy). Both are obeying the original order of the cards, and the instruction to "deal the cards based on suit" doesn't automatically tell the dealer (who represents the DBMS) which strategy was intended.

If the final piles of cards are the groups from a `GROUP BY`, then `MIN()` and `MAX()` represent picking up each pile and looking for the lowest or highest value, regardless of the order they are in. But because you can look inside the groups, you can do other things too, like adding up the total value of each pile (`SUM`) or how many cards there are (`COUNT`) etc, making `GROUP BY` much more powerful than an "ordered `DISTINCT`" could be.

Comment: @Tommy The example in your column has no `ORDER BY` in the outer query, so the DBMS can return the results in whatever order it likes - basically, whichever comes to hand first. Similarly, if you specify anything in the `ORDER BY` clause which could not exist in the `SELECT` clause, the DBMS is free to either guess, or tell you there is a logical error in your query.

Comment: As for ordering of operations being ridiculous, I took great pains to repeat that this is a **logical** ordering: however the DBMS actually implements the query, it **must** behave as though this order of events took place. If it was free to interpret your SQL in a completely different logical order, you wouldn't be able to write a query and know how it would behave.

Comment: Actually, re-reading, I think you meant that it's ridiculous that you can't, as a user, change that logical order manually. But that wouldn't help you, because as you say, a `DISTINCT` that ran *after* an `ORDER BY` would still need to know which of each set of duplicates to keep - the first or the last? Once you had syntax to choose that, you might as well use `ORDER BY MIN` as in the working example provided.

Comment: "Actually, re-reading, I think you meant that it's ridiculous that you can't, as a user, change that logical order manually", yes, this is exactly what I meant, I was complaining about SQL. And from my original question it was clear that I wanted it to keep the FIRST of the set of duplicates, which preserves the ORDER BY clause called earlier. If you keep the last, you are essentially destroying the order by!

Comment: @Tommy I wasn't saying your question wasn't clear about wanting to keep first, I was saying that the DBMS can't possibly know that. If you keep the last of each set of duplicates, you are still choosing based on the order, so it would have to be defined *somewhere* that "keeping first" is better than "keeping last". Which is irrelevant speculation, because SQL provides the tool you need, it just doesn't look how you expected it to.

Comment: Consider a very easy example, insert(1,2),(2,4),(1,3). THen select distinct col(1) order by col(2). HOw on Earth could one justify returning (2,1) instead of (1,2)? If you choose the last, you completely destroy the order by.

Comment: So why can't sql provide the tool I need in the form of a DISCTINT_KEEP_FIRST? That is ultimately what I wanted =).

Comment: @Tommy "How on Earth could one justify returning (2,1) instead of (1,2)?" Picture someone sorting a pack of cards, then dealing them face up into piles. The ones showing at the end will be the *last of each group, according to the sorted order*. The order hasn't been "destroyed", it's absolutely central to the result, and the process is entirely logical.

Comment: @Tommy there are various ways to do this in SQL. Some DBMS have more ways to do it, some less. Postgres has something that is more close to what you describe, it's called `DISTINCT ON`

Comment: @IMSoP ok, back to your answer. If ORDER BY is run last, then I don't understand how your suggested answer works, since the group by will consolidate all foo_numbers first, so in that case what does min(bar_number) do? Indeed if I remove the min clause I get the same result in your example scrible.

Comment: @Tommy The difference is that with `GROUP BY`, the values haven't been thrown away, just put into groups; `min(bar_number)` gets to look at all the `bar_number`s in a group, and see which is the lowest. As for the example, I guess my arbitrary values coincidentally pop up in the right order; try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d58f7/2 vs this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d58f7/1

Comment: @imsop ah, so it internally maintains a list of bar_numbers for each foo_number, takes the minumum of each of these lists, then sorts it by those computed minimums. Got that. Last question, then I will accept this answer. Great thanks to all your help! Is the following the correct way to also pull the bar that led to the sorting? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d58f7/5

Comment: @Tommy Yep, that's it exactly. Incidentally, I've edited bits of the answer to (hopefully) make it a bit clearer what `GROUP BY` is doing.

Comment: @ypercube: there is _no_ way to do this in SQL, because _order_ is not defined. IMHO you are only confirming the mental delusions of the OP and mysql, which does not help.

Comment: @wildplasser I suspect you and ypercube are just using different values of "this" (insert JS joke here...)

Answer (score 3):

I would go for something like

```
select col1
from (
select col1,
       rank () over(order by col2) pos
from table
)
group by col1
order by min(pos)
```

In the subquery I calculate the position, then in the main query I do a group by on col1, using the smallest position to order.

Here the [demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24dea/2) (this was Oracle, the MySql info was added later.

**Edit for MySql:**

```
select col1
from (
select col1 col1,
       @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS pos
from table1, (select @curRank := 0) p
) sub
group by col1
order by min(pos)
```

And here [the demo for MySql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08422/3).

Comment: You don't need variables for this query.

Comment: This is massively overkill for what the OP needs, which is just a better understanding of `GROUP BY` and aggregates. If you're sorting by an ungrouped column, you generally want `min()` or `max()` of that column.

Comment: I know guys, but the solution was so trivial that I thought Tommy already tried it :) Anyway in case it's not possible to use min/max, here is another solution :) Anyway there is another way to have rank with MySql? (in case you need it?)

Comment: @mucio Welcome to StackOverflow; it's best not to assume *anything* about the people asking questions (positive or negative). If the solution seems too obvious, ask why it didn't work out before jumping in with something more advanced which may not be applicable to their situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` in the referenced answer isn't attempting to perform an ordering... it is simply picking a single associated value for the column that we want to be distinct.

Like @bluefeet states, if you want a guaranteed ordering, you *must* use `ORDER BY`.

Why can't we specify a value in the `ORDER BY` that isn't included in the `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Consider the following values for `col1` and `col2`:

```
create table yourTable (
  col_1 int,
  col_2 int
);

insert into yourTable (col_1, col_2) values (1, 1);
insert into yourTable (col_1, col_2) values (1, 3);
insert into yourTable (col_1, col_2) values (2, 2);
insert into yourTable (col_1, col_2) values (2, 4);
```

With this data, what should `SELECT DISTINCT col_1 FROM yourTable ORDER BY col_2` return?

That's why you need the `GROUP BY` and the aggregate function, to decide which of the multiple values for `col_2` you should order by... could be `MIN()`, could be `MAX()`, maybe even some other function such as `AVG()` would make sense in some cases; it all depends on the specific scenario, which is why you need to be explicit:

```
select col_1
from yourTable
group by col_1
order by min(col_2)
```

### <kbd>[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8800/1)</kbd>

Comment: if we do the ordering first, we get (1,1) (2,2),(1,3),(2,4). It should then return (1,1) and (2,2), and scrap (1,3) and (2,4) which is exactly what I want. Where is the ambiguity?>

Comment: You're assuming that the `distinct` should only return the first value it encounters... why not the last / most recent value it encounters? That seems just as valid, and could give completely different results.

Comment: that is exactly my point! As to whether its invalid, if you run DISTINCT On (3,5,3), the result (3,5) can be argued to be more "naturally temporally" than (5,3). The first one just seems the most logical to me given that I have already specified (3,5,3) is an ordered list ordered by some other clause.

Comment: Ah, so the argument is that the `distinct` should infer a `MIN()` aggregation since the `order by` was `ASC`, and temporally `MIN()` and `ASC` go together.  That's too subjective and specific to your intentions in this specific scenario to be applied universally.  I can just as easily imagine a scenario where I want a `MAX()` aggregation applied to my `distinct`, but then I want to order the results ascending instead of descending.  It's a lot simpler if SQL just forces the desired behavior to be explicitly stated instead of attempting to infer the intention based on other parts of the query.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Incidentally, that's why I find Postgres's `DISTINCT ON` really hard to follow: the behaviour is well-defined, but you have to jump between the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses to see what data will actually be returned.

Comment: @IMSoP That's interesting... I don't have any hands-on experience with Postgres, so I learned something new today with `DISTINCT ON`...

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL only, when you select columns that are not in the GROUP BY it will return columns from the first record in the group. You can use this behavior to select which record is returned from each group like this:

```
SELECT foo_number, bar_number
FROM 
(
  SELECT foo_number, bar_number 
  FROM some_table 
  ORDER BY bar_number
) AS t
GROUP BY foo_number
ORDER BY bar_number DESC;
```

This is more flexible because it allows you to order the records within each group using expressions that are not possible with aggregates - in my case I wanted to return the one with the shortest string in another column.

For completeness, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  s.NamespaceId,
  s.Symbol,
  s.EntityName
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    m.NamespaceId,
    i.Symbol, 
    i.EntityName
  FROM ImportedSymbols i
  JOIN ExchangeMappings m ON i.ExchangeMappingId = m.ExchangeMappingId
  WHERE
    i.Symbol NOT IN 
    (
      SELECT Symbol 
      FROM tmp_EntityNames
      WHERE NamespaceId = m.NamespaceId
    )
      AND
    i.EntityName IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY LENGTH(i.RawSymbol), i.RawSymbol
) AS s
GROUP BY s.NamespaceId, s.Symbol;
```

What this does is return a distinct list of symbols in each namespace, and for duplicated symbols returns the one with the shortest RawSymbol. When the RawSymbol lengths are the same, it returns the one who's RawSymbol comes first alphabetically.