# T-SQL select distinct a int column without sort order

Tags: t-sql, distinct

I have a int column called "RootID" with values:

```
3
3
3
6
6
5
4
```

I want to select unique values in this column, i use distinct clause like this:

```
select distinct RootID from MyTable.
```

The result is "3 4 5 6".

But i want result is "3 6 5 4" . (actual appearance of rows).

I want a result with actual appearance of rows, without auto order .
Do you have any suggest????

Comment: If you don't define an order then you can't rely on any specific order in any query.

Comment: The order you see on the screen is not an implicit order in the data.Maybe add an identity column and order by that.

Comment: There is no inherent order, do you want a random order? Is this the only column, is `RootId` the PK? If you want to preserve the order of creation add a `datetime` column and order by that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: How to keep rows order with DISTINCT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026234/sql-how-to-keep-rows-order-with-distinct)

Comment: @N34_panda: i tried it but it still return 3-4-5-6.

Comment: Yeah, i realised my previous answer was wrong - the only way I have done this in the past is by using another column with ORDER and GROUP BY I think...Led you down the wrong path there (I deleted post)!

Comment: @TimSchmelter: i want a result with actual appearance of rows, not ramdom order.

Comment: @Achilles_VN: there is _no_ actual appearance of rows. By the way, where do they appear for you, in SSMS? Don't rely on the order if you don't specify one. Rows are not ordered at all in a table by default. You have to specify an `ORDER BY ColumnName` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no auto order. DISTINCT operator does not preserve the ordering, so you get distinct results in undefined order. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Table are set. Set doesn't have order. Appearance of rows is random by definition. Occasionally, they are sorted by Id because SQL Server read them from clustered index which is sorted.