# How to maintain the order of the data while selecting the distinct values of column from Dataset

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset as below,

```
+------+------+---------------+
| col1 | col2 |  sum(costs)   |
+------+------+---------------+
|    1 | a    | 3555204326.27 |
|    4 | b    | 22273491.72   |
|    5 | c    | 219175.00     |
|    3 | a    | 219175.00     |
|    2 | c    | 75341433.37   |
+------+------+---------------+
```

I need to select the distinct values of the col1 and my resultant dataset should have the order as 1, 4, 5, 3, 2 (the order in which these values are available in initial dataset). But the order is getting shuffled. Is there any way to maintain the same order as the intital dataset. Any suggestion in Spark/SQL could be fine.

This dataset can be obtained by below sequence in spark.

```
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
  [(1, a, 355.27), (4, b, 222.98), (5, c, 275.00), (3, a, 25.00),
   (2, c, 753.37)], ('Col1', 'col2', 'cost'));
```

Comment: Can you add to your question where the data is coming from (CSV, database), if the source is immutable or not, AND which version of Spark you are using...

Answer (score 1):

You can add another column containing the index of each row, then sort on that column after "distinct". Here is an example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(1, 4, 4, 5, 2)
  .toDF("a")
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
// +---+---+
// |  a| id|
// +---+---+
// |  1|  0|
// |  4|  1|
// |  4|  2|
// |  5|  3|
// |  2|  4|
// +---+---+

df.dropDuplicates("a").sort("id").show()
// +---+---+
// |  a| id|
// +---+---+
// |  1|  0|
// |  4|  1|
// |  5|  3|
// |  2|  4|
// +---+---+
```

Note that to do distinct on 1 specific column, you can use `dropDuplicates`, if you want to control which row you want to take in case of duplicate then use `groupBy`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to remote the duplicates in `col2` (as there are none in `col1`), so that the final result would be:

```
+----+----+---------------+
|col1|col2|            sum|
+----+----+---------------+
|   1|   a|3.55520432627E9|
|   4|   b|  2.227349172E7|
|   5|   c|       219175.0|
+----+----+---------------+
```

You could add an index column like:

```
df = df.withColumn("__idx", monotonically_increasing_id());
```

Then do all the transformations you want, and then drop it, like in:

```
df = df.dropDuplicates("col2").orderBy("__idx").drop("__idx");
```

This would mean do:

Step 1: load the data and stuff:

```
+----+----+---------------+
|col1|col2|            sum|
+----+----+---------------+
|   1|   a|3.55520432627E9|
|   4|   b|  2.227349172E7|
|   5|   c|       219175.0|
|   3|   a|       219175.0|
|   2|   c|  7.534143337E7|
+----+----+---------------+
```

Step 2: add the index:

```
+----+----+---------------+-----+
|col1|col2|            sum|__idx|
+----+----+---------------+-----+
|   1|   a|3.55520432627E9|    0|
|   4|   b|  2.227349172E7|    1|
|   5|   c|       219175.0|    2|
|   3|   a|       219175.0|    3|
|   2|   c|  7.534143337E7|    4|
+----+----+---------------+-----+
```

Step 3: transformations (here remove the dups in `col2`) and remove the `__idx` column:

```
+----+----+---------------+
|col1|col2|            sum|
+----+----+---------------+
|   1|   a|3.55520432627E9|
|   4|   b|  2.227349172E7|
|   5|   c|       219175.0|
+----+----+---------------+
```

The Java code could be:

```
package net.jgp.books.spark.ch12.lab990_others;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

/**
 * Keeping the order of rows during transformations.
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class KeepingOrderApp {

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeepingOrderApp app = new KeepingOrderApp();
    app.start();
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   */
  private void start() {
    // Creates a session on a local master
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("Splitting a dataframe to collect it")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = createDataframe(spark);
    df.show();

    df = df.withColumn("__idx", monotonically_increasing_id());
    df.show();

    df = df.dropDuplicates("col2").orderBy("__idx").drop("__idx");
    df.show();
  }

  private static Dataset<Row> createDataframe(SparkSession spark) {
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "col1",
            DataTypes.IntegerType,
            false),
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "col2",
            DataTypes.StringType,
            false),
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "sum",
            DataTypes.DoubleType,
            false) });

    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(1, "a", 3555204326.27));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(4, "b", 22273491.72));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(5, "c", 219175.0));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(3, "a", 219175.0));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(2, "c", 75341433.37));

    return spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add an index column to your DB and then in your SQL request make an ORDER BY id

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to reformat your query and use group by instead of distinct like this answer suggests [SQL: How to keep rows order with DISTINCT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026234/sql-how-to-keep-rows-order-with-distinct)